# Angular 7 - Multiple SVG images copy and paste

Tags: html, typescript, angular7, adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to implement copying multiple images from adobe illustrator and pasting it in web page to upload. I could achieve the same for single image but when I copy multiple images, all the images together act as single image. 
Below is the code

```
<mat-card class="imageUpload" (paste)=handlePaste($event)></mat-card>

handlePaste(event: any) {
    const items = (event.clipboardData || 
event.originalEvent.clipboardData).items;
    let blob = null;
    for (const item of items) {
        if (item.type.indexOf('image') === 0) {
          blob = item.getAsFile();
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (evt: any) => {
              this.onUpload("blob.name", evt.target.result);
            };
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: probably Illustrator puts one combined image on the clipboard. I guess `items.count` to be 1?

Comment: @Arjan I think the same. But is there anyway to split the images or any configuration on adobe illustrator not to make it one combined image?

Comment: I do not know the configuration options of Illustrator. In my experience with other programs, though, the way a program uses the clipboard, (which formats are put on on the clipboard and how) is usualy not document or configurable